# Why In Unity5, does my triggercollider2D only sense collisions with certain objects and not others?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I'm using a trigger collider (a circleCollider2D with is trigger checked) but it's only sensing collisions with certain objects.

here's the script on the trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Scoring : MonoBehaviour {

public updateScore updateScore;
Transform earth;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    earth = GetComponent<Transform>();
}
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("other collider " + other);
    updateScore.score++;    
}
}
```

it's sensing this object:

it's a 2D meteor object that has a rigidbody2D and a circleCollider2D on it.
it has this script attached:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CometMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 0.5f;
Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 direction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    direction = new Vector2(Random.Range(10.0f, -10.0f), Random.Range(10.0f, -10.0f));
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(direction * speed);

}


}
```

But it's not sensing this below object. I need it to sense this below object:

It's an earth object with a rigidbody2d and CircleCollider2D, pretty much the same as the meteor object.
it has this script attached:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class EarthController : MonoBehaviour {

public float force = 0.5f;
Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 direction;
Transform transform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    direction = new Vector2(0, 4);
    transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}

//  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
//      SceneManager.LoadScene("Level 01");
//
//  }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")){
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        if(transform.position.x <= 0 && transform.position.y <= 4){
            direction = new Vector2(0, -4);
        } else {
            direction = new Vector2(0, 4);
        }

        rb.AddForce(direction * force);
        Debug.Log("going this fast: " + rb.inertia);
    } else {
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) :

> If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, **collisions** or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore

```
if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")){
    rb.isKinematic = false;
    // ...
} else {
    rb.isKinematic = true;
}
```

Also, check your [Physics parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) ?

Make sure both of your colliders are not triggers. Not sure about this one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I figured it out. I had a DistanceJoint2D also on the earth object that had a box called "enable collision" that was unchecked. I checked the box and it's working perfectly now